# Can you create a TestNG Listener for your own needs

Tags: java, html, selenium, automation, testng

I've come up with a concept for a TestNG listener that would be beneficial to my needs.

I basically want to create my own listener that will create a report using a sample HTML report.

My idea is that the listener like all others will be declared in the XML.

However I want my listener to look at the XML and look at how many classes are declared and know how many tests classes are to be executed.

I can then in my report show a progress bar of the amount of Test Classes that are too be executed, then in turn providing a live feed of the progress of the tests classes.

An example would be if in my XML I have 5 tests classes declared and in the HTML report it shows a progress bar showing 0 out of 5.

As the tests are run and finished the progress bar will update showing real time progress of the tests being executed.

Is this idea feasible/possible with TestNG? Would I be able to create my own Listener to do what I want to achieve?

Any articles/advice to get me on the right path would be beneficial.

EDIT: Might not have asked the question the best way possible, so any criticism or edit suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how it is possible if you expect the listener generate the report because HTML is something static by definition. And it could be hard to add nodes a the right place.

What it could be possible is having your [ITestListener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-listeners) which runs an http server and exposes data via REST. Then you'll have your html with some javascript pooling the rest service to check progress of the suite test.

Comment: that is extremely interesting. You see that was the only idea have to achieve what I want but your idea seems extremely interesting. Is there anyway you can email/pm and explain more in depth? I'm not familiar with REST?

Comment: In fact, I used REST as common word. You just need a way to communicate between your javascript and java. The simpliest way is HTTP with json. If you want a "state of the art" solution" but more compicate, you can have a look at WebSocket.

Comment: Thanks , I will have a look into your proposals :)

Comment: For this to work, you need your html report running on the server.